# Simple Injector decorator and covariance

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, ioc-container, simple-injector

I have an application where I have multiple connection strings for my `DbContext` implementations. To support this in the consuming classes, I've created an `IDbContextProvider` interface with a `Get` method that can provide me with the `DbContext` instances I need.

I've also got an `ICommandHandler` thing going, and I'm trying to create a decorator that will call `DbContext.SaveChangesAsync()` on successful command execution. I'm registering my decorator like this:

```
container.RegisterDecorator(typeof(ICommandHandler<>),
    typeof(SaveChangesCommandHandlerDecorator<>));
```

Now, because I don't want to add a type parameter for the `DbContext` implementaiton, and I know all classes derived from `DbContext` have a `SaveChangesAsync()` method, I figured I could use covariance. So my interface looks like this:

```
public public interface IDbContextProvider<out TDbContext> where TDbContext : DbContext
{
    TDbContext Get(DbPrivileges privileges);
}
```

And the relevant part of my decorator:

```
public class SaveChangesCommandHandlerDecorator<TCommand> : ICommandHandler<TCommand> 
    where TCommand : ICommand
{
    private readonly ICommandHandler<TCommand> _handler;
    private readonly IDbContextProvider<DbContext> _dbContextProvider;

    public SaveChangesCommandHandlerDecorator(
        ICommandHandler<TCommand> handler, IDbContextProvider<DbContext> dbContextProvider)
    {
        _handler = handler;
        _dbContextProvider = dbContextProvider;
    }

    ...
```

However, when I call `Verify()` on my container, it complains that the `IDbContextProvider` is invalid, as it's looking for the "base" `IDbContextProvider<DbContext>` instead of one of the ones registered in my app.

> The constructor of type SaveChangesCommandHandlerDecorator<CreateUserCommand> contains the parameter with name 'dbContextProvider' and type IDbContextProvider<DbContext> that is not registered.Please ensure IDbContextProvider<DbContext> is registered, or change the constructor of SaveChangesCommandHandlerDecorator<CreateUserCommand>. Note that there exists a registration for a different type (Redacted).IDbContextProvider<TDbContext> while the requested type is (Redacted).IDbContextProvider<Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext>.

This actually makes sense, since Simple Injector has no way of knowing what concrete type to inject into the `dbContextProvider` parameter.

Is there any way of customizing the way my decorator is created, so that it can peek at the dependencies of the underlying `ICommandHandler` implementation's dependencies, and pick the `IDbContextProvider` signature from there on creation? So if my command handler has a `IDbContextProvider<AwesomeDbContext>`, I want that to be resolved for my decorator as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So let me get this straight: your application contains multiple `DbContext` implemtantations, such as:

- AwesomeDbContext
- EventBetterDbContext
- BrilliantDbContext

Now each command handler will typically depend on one particular `DbContext` implementation, by getting an `IDbContextProvider<TDbContext>` where the `TDbContext` is the specific `DbContext` implementation.

Now depending on what the decorator command handler depends upon, you wish to inject that exact same `IDbContextProvider<TDbContext>` implementation in the decorator as well, so you can save the changes for that particular instance.

If I summarize your question correctly, the short answer to your question is: no, you can't do that.

The longer answer is, yes this is actually possible by adding an extra generic type argument for `TDbContext` to your `SaveChangesCommandHandlerDecorator<TCommand, TDbContext>` decorator, and use the `RegisterDecorator` overload that accepts the `Func<DecoratorPredicateContext, Type>`. Using the supplied `DecoratorPredicateContext` to the factory delegate, you can analyze its `Expression` property to find out which `IDbContextProvider<TDbContext>` is injected, and based on that information you build a partially-closed version of `SaveChangesCommandHandlerDecorator<TCommand, TDbContext>` where you fill in `TDbContext` but leave `TCommand` open for Simple Injector to fill in.

But to be honest, I wouldn't take this route. It takes a lot of work, leads to hard to understand code, and your coworkers will hate you for this.

Instead, try injecting a list of `IDbContextProvider<TDbContext>` instances into the decorator instead. You can do that by making the `IDbContextProvider<out TDbContext>` registrations both separately, and as part of a collection using `RegisterCollection`.

When you inject the collection, the decorator can simply call save changes on all the `DbContext` instances. `SaveChanges` will be really fast when there are no changes, so from a performance perspective, I don't think there is anything to worry about.

Comment: Yep, this summarized my question correctly and thanks for the detailed answer! I didn't consider the collection route but it will definitely produce cleaner code, so I'll go for that.